# Width not applying for class container in IE 9

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply width for .container class but ie is not taking any changes of css.If any body have any idea let me know.Bellow is my code.

```
<!-- [if ie 9]>
.nav > li > a{
padding-left: 20px !important;
}
 .container{
max-width: 1350px !important;
width: 1350px !important;
}
<![endif]-->
```

[My website link](http://banditbuster.com/home-2/)

[image: This is screen shot what i am getting]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conditional comments are meant to be used in the html markup, not the css. (See [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) for usage)

There are hacks for css to target ie9, such as as `/9` or ... this:

```
/* target Internet Explorer 9 and Internet Explorer 10:*/

    @media screen and (min-width:0\0) { 
        /* ie9+ code here */
        ...
    }
```

Check this example **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/pyvL6/1/)** in IE9+ and other browsers